# Wagtail Admin Multi Class Model

Tags: python, django, wagtail

So, I'm trying to add extra fields in from a separate class in my model into a wagtail_hook that extends ModelAdmin.

You can see in my model that there are two classes, one is Report this is the main class, and the other is Sender. In the Wagtail admin I would like to add the Sender content to the report page.

Is there a way to do this with wagtail?

Here is my model.py

```
class Report(models.Model):

    # Django will set the ID
    Pay_Period_Start_Date   = models.DateTimeField('Pay Period Start Date')
    Pay_Period_End_Date    = models.DateTimeField('Pay Period End Date')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Report for:" + str(self.Pay_Period_Start_Date) + " to " + str(self.Pay_Period_End_Date)


class Sender(models.Model):

    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    Family_Name = models.CharField(('Family_Name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    Given_Name =    models.CharField(('Given_Name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    Email_Address = models.CharField(('Email_Address'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    Telephone_Number = models.CharField(('Telephone_Number'), max_length=30, blank=True)
```

here is my wagtail_hook.py

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import Report, Sender

class CHModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Report
    menu_label = 'Clearing House'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'form'  # change as required
    menu_order = 300  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = False # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view
    list_display = ('Pay_Period_Start_Date', 'Pay_Period_End_Date')
    search_fields = ('Pay_Period_Start_Date')
    list_filter = ('Pay_Period_Start_Date', 'Pay_Period_End_Date')

# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(CHModelAdmin)
```

Comment: What do you want to do that can't be achieved simply by moving the 'sender' fields into the Report model?

Comment: Sender has no field named 'Pay_Period_Start_Date' and I need the data from both classes

Comment: Also each month has a report, and a report has multi senders